# Refresh OutputCache on Expire C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I am creating a web application, which queries the database and gets data from it. I need to use the `OutputCaching` to cache the data retrieved from database. My question is, is it possible to automatically cache from the database again as soon as it's expired.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you think about your question, you're really asking *"Is there an active process that can either be notified or be able to poll `OutputCache` and act on certain events (expiration)".* Or variations of this, where an external component is able to mimic enough of `OutputCache` functionality in addition to extending it with "content expiration" event of some sort. The answer to all such question flavors is *"no such animal exist out of the box, but you can certainly craft one yourself if you requirements warrant such complexity".*